# Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Switch'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref, create-ref

I am getting a `Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Switch'.` message from `TypeScript` for `this.checked` and `this.disabled` createRefs. Also, on the last line, I am also getting a `Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Switch` warning from `TS`. How can I fix these warnings?

```
interface Props {
  checked: boolean;
  onChange: (checked: boolean) => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

interface States {
  checked: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export default class Switch extends React.PureComponent<Props, States> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.checked = React.createRef(); // comment this line out to use as controlled component
    this.disabled = React.createRef(); // comment this line out to use as controlled component
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
      disabled: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <div ref={this.checked}> // TypeScript warns: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Switch'
```

Comment: What if you extends an `React.Component` instead of `React.PureComponent`?

Comment: Didn't help sorry

Comment: Why do you use ```any``` as ```props``` type in the constructor signature instead of ```Props```?

Comment: @НиколайГольцев good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you need to define this variables before using them with `this`. Just define them `private` or `public` or what you want. It type will be the result of a `React.createRef()` so an `React.RefObject` object. If you know on which node element you will use the `ref`, then you can precise it in the type.

For example you use `this.checked` on a `div`, so you can define it like `React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>`. If you don't know it yet, use `React.RefObject<unknown>`:

```js
export default class Switch extends React.PureComponent<Props, States> {
  private checked: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  private disabled: React.RefObject<unknown>;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.checked = React.createRef(); // comment this line out to use as controlled component
    this.disabled = React.createRef(); // comment this line out to use as controlled component
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
      disabled: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.checked} />;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit lucid-galileo-neckr]

Comment: great. It's asking me to define a type for `private checked`, what should I define it as? Or just use `any`?